# Problem with ActivateItem by the ContextMenu on DataGrid using CaliburnMicro

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am using caliburn micro on my project. So far I have had no problems with ActivateItemAsync. Now, however, this method does not activate my ActiveItem. Now what my code looks like:

I have a DashboardMainView:

```
 <Grid >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Ribbon ...>
    </Ribbon>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="#E8E8E8">
        <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
```

Then in DashboardMainViewModel:

```
public class DashboardMainViewModel : Conductor<object>
{
    private IDialogCoordinator dialogCoordinator;

    public DashboardMainViewModel(IDialogCoordinator instance)
    {
        this.dialogCoordinator = instance;
        ActivateItemAsync(new DashboardSummaryViewModel());
    }
    public async Task Execution()
    {
        await ActivateItemAsync(new BasicExecutionViewModel(DialogCoordinator.Instance));
    }
```

So far everything works, but then BasicExecutionView is activated, where I have a DataGrid and MenuContext in it. And here comes the problem, when we right-click on the DataGrid, a menu pops up where, after selecting an interesting option, it should activate another view ... but it does not. My code looks like this:

```
<Grid >
    <Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
    <DataGrid 
        x:Name="BasicExecutionGrid"
        CanUserSortColumns="True"
        IsReadOnly="True"
        CanUserAddRows="False"
        FontSize="11"
        Height ="800"
        ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AutoGeneratingColumn="BasicExecutionGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn">
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                       Text="{Binding}" 
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSteelBlue"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="45"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Details" 
                              Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=DataContext.ActivateCellDetailsView}"
                              >
                    </MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

In BasicExecutionViewModel I have:

```
    class BasicExecutionViewModel : Conductor<object>
{
    private IDialogCoordinator dialogCoordinator;


    private RelayCommand activateCellDetailsView { get; set; }

    public BasicExecutionViewModel(IDialogCoordinator instance)
    {
        this.dialogCoordinator = instance;
    }

    public ICommand ActivateCellDetailsView
    {
        get
        {
            if (activateCellDetailsView == null)
            {
                activateCellDetailsView = new RelayCommand(async p=> await ActivateCellView());
            }
            return activateCellDetailsView;
        }
    }
    public async Task ActivateCellView()
    {
        await ActivateItemAsync(new CellDetailsExecutionViewModel());
    }
}
```

The code comes to ActivateCellView () and activates it. I can see it in Output Window where ActiveItem takes the value of the CellDetailsExecutionViewModel () object, but BasicExecutionView is still displayed on the screen. What am I doing wrong? I guess it's something with either DataContext or parent-child issue ... please help :)

PS. I'm not a professional programmer I'm a hobbyist.

### Solved

I solved the problem. My mistake was using `Conductor<object>` incorrectly. In DashboardMainViewModel. When I corrected on

```
DashboardMainViewModel: Conductor<object>.Collection.OneActive
```

ant the same in the BasicExecutionViewModel

```
BasicExecutionViewModel: Conductor<object>.Collection.OneActive
```

I also updated the code in the ActivateCellView() method to

```
        public async Task ActivateCellView()
    {
        CellDetailsExecutionViewModel cellDetailsExecutionViewAcvtivate = new CellDetailsExecutionViewModel();
        var parentConductor = (Conductor<object>.Collection.OneActive)(this.Parent);
        await parentConductor.ActivateItemAsync(cellDetailsExecutionViewAcvtivate);
    }
```

And everything works beautifully